# Jmeter Cookie data is missing in request | Getting Object Moved in response and page is redirecting to login page itself again and again

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

[Error in Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqGCf.png) I'm working on Jmeter and found the authentication is set in cookies. I have added the cookie manager and still finding a redirected response. We have tried follow redirects and redirect automatically settings itself in Jmeter http request and After lot of tries I just found the cookie data is missing in the request sent to the servers.

**Cookie Data:**
CHMHC%2fMAS%2fWebPortal%2fv2019_testing2_Web.session=; n0=0%2c0%7c; m0=0%2C0%7C

This is after entering the credentials in Login page with Post request.

This is ASP.Net application

How to add this data along with the request sent.[Cookie Data entered partially[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W38or.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide

You might have to turn on one setting in jmeter.properties

[image]